# Angular JS : $exceptionHandler without try or throw block?

Tags: angularjs, try-catch, exceptionhandler

```
 app.factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
      return function(exception, cause) {
        exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
        throw exception;
      };
  });
```

Is it possible to handle all the exception globally in angularJs using `$exceptionHandler` without writing `try` or `throw` block?

What I want is even if I forget to write the `try-catch` block for the statements like var `a=1/0`, I want to handle it in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, global error handling in AngularJS is possible.** Basically, at config time, you [decorate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) the [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) service in order to modify its default behaviour.
The code would look something like this:

```
angular
  .module('global-exception-handler', [])
  .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide
      .decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
          return function(exception, cause) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            // Do something here
          };
        }]);
  }]);
```

**Note:** in some cases, you should also call `$delegate` as it's the original service instance. In this case, taking a look at [$exceptionHandler's code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/exceptionHandler.js#L46), it only does this:

```
$log.error.apply($log, arguments);
```

**Source:** [John Papa's Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#exception-handling)